# Images Slideshow from folder [Only PHP]

Tags: php

I made an upload form called `upload.php` with action `up.php` so I upload images in the folder `C:/xampp/htdocs/uploadimages` and in the page `upload.html` I would like to make a dynamic slideshow containing all new and old pictures.

> upload.php

```
<body>
    <form action="up.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h2>Upload File</h2>
        <label for="fileSelect">Filename:</label>
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
        <p><strong>Note:</strong> Only <b> .jpg </b> and <b> .png </b> formats allowed to a max size of 3 MB.</p>
    </form>

    <div class="gallery">
        <div class="gallery-image">
            <?php 
                    $directory = "C:/xampp/htdocs/uploadimages";
                    $images = glob($directory . "/*.jpg");

                    foreach($images as $image)
                    {
                    echo " <img src=\"basename($image)\"> ";
                    echo "<br>" ;
                    }
            ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

> up.php

```
<?php
$target_dir = "C:/xampp/htdocs/uploadimages/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

if (file_exists($target_file)) {
  echo "File already exists. <br>";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 3 * 1024 * 1024) {
  echo "Your file is too large. <br>";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png") {
  echo "Only JPG and PNG files are allowed. <br>";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "";
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded. <br>";
  } else {
    echo "There was an error uploading your file. <br>";
  }
}

?>
```

I tried the `basename($image)` inside a `for-each` loop but nothing worked

Comment: You escaping the qoutes. Try: ` echo " <img src='PATH_TO\'" . $image . " ' \> ";`

Comment: didnt work man, all i was trying to do is add these images in a slideshow and add an interval 2 seconds to change pic